What do scholars have to say on the root of Verse 20 of Job 19?
We read in Job 19:19-20(NIV):

All my intimate friends detest me;
those I love have turned against me . I am nothing but skin and bones;
I have escaped only by the skin of my teeth.

< Footnote under Verse 20 says : that is' by my gums.'   In modern language, the phrase means: to escape narrowly. Was Job quoting a proverb of his time ? Or, was he coining a new phrase to express his plight ? What do scholars have to say on the root of Verse 20 of Job 19 ?

The pertinent phrase in Job 19:20 is the last two words בְּעֹ֣ור שִׁנָּֽי which are:

בְּע֣וֹר = a preposition, בְּ , plus the word עוֹר = skin or hide of an animal or human
שִׁנָּֽי = teeth = plural of שֵׁן = tooth (in its lexical form)

Together, these two nouns form a noun chain and thus should be translated, "by the skin of [my] teeth".
The origin of this expression, "escape by the skin of my teeth" is obscure as the Pulpit commentary freely admits:

And I am escaped with the skin of my teeth. The expression is, no doubt, proverbial, and signifies "barely escaped;" but its origin is
obscure. Job 19:20

